# EE 2.70 + DevDemon Updater 3.2.6 not working for add-ons

Tags: ee2, devdemon, devdemon-updater

I used [DevDemon Updater](https://www.devdemon.com/updater/) to update an EE install from 2.5.2 to 2.7.0 -- worked great, as usual. But, now, Updater will not update any add-ons.

When trying to update any add-on, Updater looks like it's working correctly through each step--all the way to "Done." But it silently fails to make any changes to EE.

I don't see any PHP errors in the error log. I've checked the Updater settings, as well as the EE folders' file permissions. I can update add-ons manually (copying files) and also change things (content, settings) in EE via the control panel.

I've tried a variety of add-ons, including Assets2.1.4, Matrix2.5.6, Playa4.4.5, Wygwam3.1.2, low-reorder-v221, low-search-v231, snippet_sync-135 and others. And, I can see that DevDemon is successfully unzipping these add-on files into a folder under system/expressionengine/cache/updater. The files, however, are never being copied into the proper third_party folders.

Does anyone have this combo of EE 2.70 + DevDemon Updater 3.2.6 working properly? Are others seeing this issue?

Comment: It would be nice to know which addons you tried.. From which version to what version. etc

Comment: @ManuelPayano I've added more details. I don't see any evidence that DevDemon is getting to the point of adding the files to the proper folders in EE--it appears to be failing before it gets to this step. So, I currently don't suspect the incompatibility is specific to any add-on.

Comment: I have expeerienced problems using Updater to upgrade from EE 2.6.1 to 2.7.0 - I've detailed the issue here: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/237564/ Now all of my third party plugins are failing within the CP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ManuelPayano at DevDemon was able to replicate this, which were "[addon install/update & XID issues](http://www.devdemon.com/updater/#product_version_history)" with between EE 2.70 and Updater 3.2.6.

DevDemon now has released [Updater 3.2.7](http://www.devdemon.com/updater/) with the fix, and it's again working great.